# Google Earth Engine extract values on MODIS data at point coordinates

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, modis, extract

I'm trying to extract from the MODIS collection MOD11A1006 band "LST_Day_1km" at one point coordinates the value of each image in the collection together with the date, and hour of the image and export this data to a CSV file. However, if I'm not mistaken, the code bellow gets the the "date" and "hour" when the image was taken, but for some reason I could not extract the "LST_Day_1km" band value at the point coordinates.
How this could be extracted?

```
// Site coords
var siteCoords_features = [
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point( -69.282000066708,-12.831999897556432), {name: 'site'})];

// Creates a FeatureCollection from coords
var pt_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(siteCoords_features);
print('Point', pt_collection)
Map.addLayer(pt_collection)
Map.centerObject(pt_collection, 10)

// Modis Collection
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,1,1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,12,31);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterBounds(pt_collection.geometry())
                   .select('LST_Day_1km');
 print("Collection",dataset)                 

// Extracted band Scale to Kelvin and convert to Celsius
var modLSTc = dataset.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
   .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});
print('Modis Image Colection processed:', modLSTc);
//Map.addLayer(modLSTc)

var geometry = pt_collection.geometry();
var extractData = function(img){
    var stats = img.reduceRegion({
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 30,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first()})
    return ee.Feature(geometry, {
      value: img.get('LST_Day_1km'), 
      hourStart: img.get('system:time_start'),
      hourEnd : img.get('system:time_start'),
      date: img.get('system:index'),
      lat: geometry.coordinates().get(0),
      lon: geometry.coordinates().get(1),
      })
    
}
var outputData = modLSTc.map(extractData)
print('output',outputData)


/*
// Export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: outputData,
  folder: 'GEE_results',
  fileNamePrefix: 'MODIS_LST_2015_2020',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: ['date', 'hourStart','hourEnd' ,'value', 'lat', 'lon']})
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with these time series collections, you have to be sure that they are not empty at considered geometry. First of all, I "added" as layer first image of **modLSTc** without any result. So, afterward, I could add **modLSTc** mean indicating this Image Collection is not empty. Now, I could corroborate that you didn't extract the "LST_Day_1km" band value at the point coordinates because value is in the new created variable stats; not in img. So, I modified your code as [follows](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e3fcda53397182eb2581c73fd5df8f89) for retrieving 2182 corresponding values (including nulls) for 'LST_Day_1km' and correct value for 'system:time_end'.

```
// Site coords
var siteCoords_features = [
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-69.282000066708,-12.831999897556432 ), {name: 'site'})];

// Creates a FeatureCollection from coords
var pt_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(siteCoords_features);
print('Point', pt_collection);
Map.addLayer(pt_collection);
Map.centerObject(pt_collection, 10);

// Modis Collection
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,1,1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,12,31);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterBounds(pt_collection.geometry())
                   .select('LST_Day_1km');

print("Collection",dataset);               

//Map.addLayer(dataset.first());

// Extracted band Scale to Kelvin and convert to Celsius
var modLSTc = dataset.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
   .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']);
});

print('Modis Image Colection processed:', modLSTc);
//Map.addLayer(modLSTc.mean());

var geometry = pt_collection.geometry();
var extractData = function(img){
    var stats = img.reduceRegion({
      geometry: geometry,
      scale: 30,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first()});

    return ee.Feature(geometry, {
      value: stats.get('LST_Day_1km'), 
      hourStart: img.get('system:time_start'),
      hourEnd : img.get('system:time_end'),
      date: img.get('system:index'),
      lat: geometry.coordinates().get(0),
      lon: geometry.coordinates().get(1),
      });
    
};

var outputData = modLSTc.map(extractData);
print('output',outputData);

// Export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: outputData,
  folder: 'GEE_results',
  fileNamePrefix: 'MODIS_LST_2015_2020',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'});
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, an extract of obtained CSV can be observed as follows.

[image]

It can also be observed there are many missing values for temperature (column highlighted with red rectangle).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation !!!

Comment: I have a question I wanted the night band results for the same code so I have changed where say in the code "LST_Day_1km" to "LST_Night_1km" however in the output the hour is still the same. What could be the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: None, it is OK. You have to use 'Night_view_time' (scaled by 0.1) for considering hours night range for each pixel. More information here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD11A1 .

Comment: I could do it, but in two separated CSV files. One for the LST value and the other for its hour at : https://code.earthengine.google.com/daa003540e309044ef250fa70f2188d8 How can I get in one solely CSV file: the LST value from "LST_Night_1km" band and its correspondent hour from "Night_view_time" band for the point of interest?