# Google Earth Engine, ReduceRegion crsTransform error

Tags: google-earth-engine, reduceregion

I am trying to extract the value of MODIS NDVI for the pixel closest to a given point. I followed the suggestion detailed in the accepted answer of [this post here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417370/google-earth-engine-extract-values-on-modis-data-at-point-coordinates).

Nevertheless, I found out that the "scale" factor in image.reduceRegion is dangerous: even by using a scale of 250 (which is supposed to be the [MODIS NDVI scale](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD13Q1)), yields values that are different when compared with the pixel of the actual MODIS image downloaded by [NASA EarthData](https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov).

I've read that it is possible to work around the scale issue by specifying a crsTransform as an input argument to reduceRegion and I therefore proceeded as following:

```
var siteCoords_features = [
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(14.116411,40.946856), {name: 'site'})];

var folder = 'DISCARICHE'

var pt_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(siteCoords_features);
//print('Point', pt_collection);
Map.addLayer(pt_collection);
Map.centerObject(pt_collection, 10);


var maskneg = function(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.gt(0))
}

var maskbad = function(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.select('SummaryQA').eq(0))
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(pt_collection.geometry())
.filterDate('2010-01-01','2020-12-31').map(maskbad).select('NDVI').map(maskneg);

var geometry = pt_collection.geometry()


var extractData = function(image){
  var stats = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer:ee.Reducer.first(),
    //scale: 250,
    geometry: geometry,
    crs:image.projection().crs(),
    crsTransform: image.projection().transform,
   });
  return ee.Feature(geometry,{
  value: stats.get('NDVI'),
  hourStart: image.get('system:time_start'),
  hourEnd: image.get('system:time_end'),
  date: image.get('system:index'),
  lat: geometry.coordinates().get(0),
  lon: geometry.coordinates().get(1),
  });
};

var outputData = dataset.map(extractData);
print('output',outputData);

// Export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: outputData,
  folder: folder,
  fileNamePrefix: 'GIUGLIANO_MODIS_NDVI_2010_2020',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'});
```

Now, if I use:

```
crsTransform: image.projection().transform
```

Google Earth Engine stops with the error:

```
Invalid argument specified for ee.List(): function(){var d=Fa.apply(0,arguments).map(function(f){return c.mq(f)}),e=a.hasOwnProperty("prototype")?c.mq(this):void 0;d=b4a(c,a,d,e);return c.xj(d)}
```

And if I use:

```
crsTransform: image.projection().transform()
```

It stops with the error:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=2010_01_01):
Image.reduceRegion, argument 'crsTransform': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Float>.
Actual type: String.
Actual value: PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 231.65635826395825], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", -20015109.354], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -231.65635826395834], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 8895604.157336]]
```

What should I do?

Another source of error in the NDVI value of Google Earth Engine vs. the actual MODIS NDVI could be the selection of a different pixel compared with the geometry. Is there a way to display the extracted pixel on the map to see if it's actually the closest to the geometry?